# Android Weird behavior keyboard on EditText

Tags: java, android, listview, keyboard, android-edittext

I implemented a listview which contains multiple edittexts. Every row in the list has such a edittext:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueEt"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/infoView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/infoView"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
```

So when you click on one of the edittexts you shall be able to enter numbers and points.

But if you click on one it shows the right keyboard (numbers + point) and then the edittext loses focus and the keyboard switches to the normal keyboard. if you click on a key nothing happens.

My Adapter:

```
public class CustomBodyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private final String[] tags;
    private final float[] values;
    private Date date;

    public CustomBodyAdapter(Context context, String[] tags, Date date, float[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row_image_text, tags);
        this.tags = tags;
        this.date = date;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_body, parent, false);

        TextView tagTv = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tagTv);
        EditText valueEt = (EditText) customView.findViewById(R.id.valueEt);
        ImageView infoView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.infoView);
        tagTv.setText(tags[position]);
        if(position == 0){
            valueEt.setText(date.toString());
            valueEt.setEnabled(false);
            infoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else if(position == 3 || position == 4 || position == 5){
            valueEt.setText(values[position] + "");
        }else{
            valueEt.setText(values[position] + "");
            infoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        return customView;
    }
}
```

And this is how I add the listview:

```
 Date today = currentCalender.getTime();
        float[] values = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        cba = new CustomBodyAdapter(BodyActivity.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bodyItems), today, values);
        listView.setAdapter(cba);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

[image: When I open the Activity]

[image: This shows 1sek when I click on an Edittext]

[image: Then the normal keyboard opens automatically]

Comment: could you add some screenshots

Comment: @piotrek1543 ok I updated